# MongoDB-PHP: How to sort the result of find query by timestamp in ascending/descending order?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I want to sort the result of find query in ascending/descending order w.r.t timestamp(time_created).

My query is:

```
$mongoResult = $mongoDb->find(array('organization_id' => new MongoId($_SESSION['user_id'])));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$mongoResult = $mongoDb->find(
  array(
    'organization_id' => new MongoId($_SESSION['user_id'])
  ))->sort(array("time_created" => -1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the _id field to sort by timestamp.

The following query can print the latest 100 records.

```
$mongoResult = $mongoDb->find()->sort( array("_id" => -1 ))->limit(100);
```